# HTML: How to un-include the included .js file on current page

Tags: javascript, html

I have an Html file in which i have include a .js file like

```
<script src="myCode.js"></script>
```

what can i do to remove that file from according to any condition later?
like:

```
if(someCondition == true )
{
  /* some code to remove myCode.js file */
  alert('myCode.js file doesnt exist on this document anymore');
}
```

Comment: Disregard close vote. Unable to retract.

Comment: Why are you using a `<link>` element to load a script file? You should use a `<script>` tag.

Comment: Changed < link > to < script >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: You can't. JavaScript files loaded like this

```
<script src="mycode.js"></script>
```

are executed as soon as the document loads. If it is possible to check the condition *during* the page load, you could use a [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.write) call to include the HTML that loads the script only if the condition is satisfied, or if the script can be loaded after the document has finished loading, you could use something like jQuery's [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/).

If it isn't possible either way, the best you can do is to try to undo everything that the script does, such as attempting to remove any functions, DOM elements, timeouts, and event handlers that have been added.

Answer (score 2):

You could rewrite your code so that it looks like this:

```
if (someCondition != true)
{
  document.write('<link type="text/javascript" href="myCode.js" />');
}
```

That way, you include the .js based on your condition.

Comment: thanks for help...!! i found that the once a .js file included cant be totally removed. I have to put a condition at the place of including.